# How to make post request with axios and save the q to localstorage react js

Tags: reactjs

i have problem with post request. i have a url that can acces by post request. and i want to login with post request by using clientid, clientsecret, username, password. and when i login, console log return error. 400.

````
      const { dispatch } = this.props;
      //alert(`Name: ${this.state.name} , Phone: ${this.state.username} , Email: ${this.state.email}  `);
      const user = {
          clientId : this.state.formData.clientId,
          clientSecret : this.state.formData.clientSecret,
          username: this.state.formData.username,
          password :this.state.formData.password,
      }

      axios.post(`http://10.50.51.21:8062/token`,{user})

      .then(res=>{
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data.user);
        // dispatch(userLogin(this.state.formData.username, this.state.formData.password));
        // customHistory.push('/Dashboard');

      })
      .catch(error=>console.log('parsing failed',error));
    }```
````

Comment: can you login using postman or similar soft?

Comment: what do u mean bro ?

Comment: I'm trying to understand is that a problem with your react app or your server. So if you could try to login with postman and let us know or even better post the postman request here that would be very helpful.

Comment: broo, that ip is office ip that can be access just when im in office. but when im at home, i use localip with fake json server, i succesfuly post . why that can happen ? sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

you are sending user object inside other object. Just remove useless curly braces:

axios.post(`http://10.50.51.21:8062/token`, user)

Comment: alerady, but still eror 401 .

Comment: when i use office ip always error. but when use local ip no error i get

Comment: Could you show your response and request headers (from network inspector) ?